# SQL Query to delete while database size is larger than 200GB

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a `SQL` table which is used to store a large number of logs.

I want to have a stored procedure or something along the lines of that. That runs every minute and deletes items from the end of the log table as long as the database size is above 200GB.

so something like:

```
While(databaseSize > 200GB)
{
Batch delete 100 entires From [dbo].[logs] OrderBy DateTime
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

[Edit]
SQL Azure limits my database size to 250GB. Hence why I need to limit and still keep a small buffer for other tables.

Comment: cannot use a maintenance plan or a job?

Comment: Remember that deleting records does not release space back to the OS. So I dont understand the rationale behind checking database size and then deleting the unwanted records. Instead the logic should be based on the no of days that you want to keep the records and delete records that are `X days older`. e.g. delete all records that are older than 180 days.

Comment: Every minute you are going to delete 100 at a time?   That is silly.

Comment: @Kin In Azure you are charge by database size.

Comment: @Kin using number of days is also tricky because some days vary a whole lot more than others.  And there could be the odd case, say December when the days get larger and my database fills up. Ps im using sql azure.

Comment: @Paparazzi Not quite. Every minute it will loop deleting 100 at a time. Most like a few thousand every minute. I mean the 100 can be changed to any number

Answer (score 1):

In a maintenance plan run something like this like hourly

```
While((select count(*) from From [dbo].[logs]) > 1000000)
begin
    delete top (10000) From [dbo].[logs] OrderBy DateTime
end
```

Comment: It is not that simple in Azure SQL.

Comment: So this is essentially keeping the first million, vs delete the last thousand approach.

Comment: @Zapnologica It is an approach with valid syntax.

Comment: This still does not directly solve my issue with relating to size. This approach assumes a standard size per db row?

Comment: No kidding.    Database size is the size allocated not the actual size of the data.   It allocates more space when it runs out of space. You are just going to need to figure out to calculate data size.

Comment: I have a new issue, Just tried to run your query to see its performance, I have just executed `select count(*) from Logs` and 20 minutes later it has still not finished executing.

Comment: OK you have some general performance issues.  Try with (nolock).

Comment: Ok so I ran it with `(nolock)` took 1 hour 25 minutes.  ( Standard 2 sql 100 DTU) Came back with answer `434688200`

Comment: I mean `50 DTU` not `100`

Answer (score 0):

To run your script on a scheduled basis you will need to build a PowerShell workflow using the Azure Automation service. There is a good walk-through of this on Azure's documentation site [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-automation-your-sql-agent-in-the-cloud/).

I will also note that there is a better version of this offering coming as "Elastic Jobs". It will offer much more control and features that are closer to what SQL Agent does for on-premise. They are opening up invotes for private previous now but you can read more about this [from Mark Vaillancourt here](http://markvsql.com/2016/11/new-elastic-database-jobs-sql-agent-for-azure-sql-database/).

Just remember that Azure SQL databases still have a log just like any other database in on-premise SQL Servers, so make sure you your delete query is optimized for log usage. It can ensure the delete runs efficiently and does not lock up the table for an extended period.